# How to add Toggle button in ListView items in android?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, togglebutton

I am working Android application, Using ListActivity to create ListView then i tried to add ToggleButton inside the ListItems, but i didn't know that, please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Here is the complete code url [android custom listview with togglebutton ](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/enabling-multi-selection-mode-in-listview-by-adding-togglebutton-using-custom-layout-in-android/)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps by which you can create Custom ListView:

1. Create row layout for your listview item which you want for ListView
2. create **custom adapter** by creating a separate class, and extend `BaseAdapter`
3. Override `getView()` method, inflate the above item row layout and display the data

For more info: [android custom listview](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+custom+listview) And if you want to learn about: [AdapterViews and Adapters](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf)